# making link <a> with data/curlybrackets {{ }} in VUE js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm looking for a way to create links to different pages with data in curly brackets {{ }},
i just can't figure out how to use them in .

```
  <div id="app">
      <div v-for="data in categorie">
        <button v-on:click=" filterFunction(data) ">{{data}}</button>
        <a href="testsite{{data}}.html"> test links </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Using Vue you can use binding of the `href`

```js
<div id="app">
      <div v-for="data in categorie">
        <button v-on:click=" filterFunction(data) ">{{data}}</button>
        <a :href="'testsite' + data + '.html'"> test links </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Please do pay attention to possible security issues, you need to sanitizer the `data` variable yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need curly braces here. Instead you should use `v-bind`:

```
 <div id="app">
      <div v-for="data in categorie">
        <button v-on:click=" filterFunction(data) ">{{data}}</button>
        <a v-bind:href="'testsite'+data+'.html'"> test links </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

With `v-bind` you mark static text of your url with single quotes and `data` just goes wherever you need

Some [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5s84hbv1/)